# What does "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'shift' of null - all.js:54 mean?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

My FB canvas app is up and running and working as it should but I'm getting this error in the JS debug console:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'shift' of null"    all.js:54

and I'm wondering if it's a problem with my code or if its because the jdk is always being worked on by the FB team. Should I be worried about it?

Thanks in advance,

Robert

Comment: it might be caused by some other error in your code. if you've made any recent changes, check them.

Comment: It is *highly* unlikely its because the SDK is always being worked on; all releases will be **stable**. It's more likely it's your code like @keune suggests.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll look into it, but its strange because everything is working

Comment: same boat here. It's Facebook JavaScript SDK's bug. If you just include the Facebook JavaScript SDK without other codes, the error is still here.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and implemented the Javascript SDK according to these [Facebook Instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) and it fixed my error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... In my code I had a `<script>` tag referencing a javascript file that didn't exist (that i hadn't created yet).
as soon as i created an empty js file that error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```